# Executable jar doesn't start normally

Tags: java, jar

I created an executable jar file with eclipse indigo, but when i double click on it nothing happens. But when i write java -jar c:/dir/filename.jar to cmd, it works. Other jars runs well. I'm using jdk 1.7.0_02 and eclipse indigo. How could i start it normally?

Comment: how are you creating executable jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a jar by double clicking it, you just have to make sure that Java is associated with .jar files. The easiest way to do this is by reinstalling the JRE (which generally does it for you).

Otherwise you will need to modify some of your Windows properties (I'm not sure what version of Windows you are running) to point .jar files to the instance of javaw.exe.

[Here's a link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/since-updating-to-windows-7-i-am-unable-to-run-any/b4b2c2fb-8634-4d26-bf76-a27cb7e6cbff) to a Windows 7 page on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

right click on .jar file and go to properties, then set "open with" program to "Java SE Binary".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by associating the .jar extension with the command to run it via javaw.exe.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\{java version}\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```