# "Couldn't find the main class" on HelloWorld

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javaw

I started with Java yesterday. I installed Eclipse, JDK and JRE and I did the HelloWorld tutorial. I followed the tutorial and it runs correctly on Eclipse. Now I want to transform it on a runnable .jar file, so I go to Export, i create it, and it apperas on the desktop.

So when I try to doubleclick it (opening it with javaw), it returns the busy cursor icon and nothing happens. On the other hand, if I open it form cmd `java -jar HelloWorld.jar`, it works properly. Is it normal? What can I do?

Comment: Already answered in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784300/executable-jar-doesnt-start-normally

Comment: When double-clicking on the jar Java opens it in `javaw.exe`, which doesn't show console output. Your code runs, you just can't see it. You can get the same result by running `javaw -jar HelloWorld.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Pietu1998 said, `javaw.exe` will actually run your program but not open a console window. This is because `javaw.exe` is meant to run GUIs which obviously does not need a command prompt. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503327/difference-between-java-exe-javaw-exe-and-jvm-dll) for what is the difference between `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`.

Even

```
javaw -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

on the command prompt will look like nothing happens. Redirect the output to a file and you'll see that your program actually ran:

```
javaw -jar HelloWorld.jar > HelloWorld.txt
```

The output of your program will be in the file `HelloWorld.txt`.

Usually all java programs do not rely on just double clicking to run but come with a kind of a `launcher` which prepares the environment - notably [setting up the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) - for your app an then runs it. It is platform dependent and if the platform allow to run it using double click then it will be run that way. Such a launcher could be just a simple script: `.bat`, `.cmd`, `.sh` or an executable `.exe`. For example, if you look at the folder where you have installed eclipse then you'll find a `eclipse.exe` file (assuming your platform is windows). Creating such a launcher is also easy and is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811974/how-to-create-a-cmd-file-to-run-jars).